# Default text must disappear in textarea upon click using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

This is my first time working with jQuery and I'm having some difficulty understanding how to implement it on my website, even though its a relatively easy task I am trying to accomplish.

My goal is to modify an existing textarea on my website so that it has a default message displayed that disappears when the client clicks on the textarea to enter his information. Originally I just wanted to use the html placeholder attribute, but for some reason it does not work.. (I am using IE 8). So now I am trying to use this jQuery code which was suggested to me.

Here is the code:

```
                    <textarea style="background: #F6E3CE; overflow:auto;" rows="3" cols="70" name="sComments" id="sComments" 
                        <script type="text/javascript"><?php
                        $("input#text").focus(function(){
                            if( $(this).val() == "default message" )
                            {
                                $(this).val("");
                            }
                        }).blur(function(){
                            if( $(this).val() == "" )
                            {
                                $(this).val("default message");
                            }
                        }); ?>
                        </script>
                        onchange="commentsChanged(this,<?php echo $pKey;?>);"><?php echo str_replace('\r\n', "\n", rtrim($variable1[0][aComments]));?></textarea>
```

If I understand correctly, I referenced the jQuery file at the beginning of my code as such:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="../js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
```

On this latest attempt, this part of the website would not even open. After doing some research I am still unsure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

EDIT: Both answers below are excellent and work great. Tenhouse's is more "proper" because it seperates logic and formatting, but Chandrakant's use of inline JavaScript works equally as well and is actually what I used on my website.

Comment: About the "for some reason" : http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Comment: You have jQuery code wrapped in PHP tags.

Comment: You can't put a script just inside a tag like this.

Comment: script tags within an element, php tags within script tags? Maybe it's time to start learning the basics, and I mean that in a good way!

Comment: And you have no element `input#text`. There are too many errors in there. I'd really suggest you to follow one or two tutorials on jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you are mixing up `PHP` code with `JavaScript` code which will not work, since they are in no direct relation.

Secondly you have to put your `focus / blur -listeners` in the `document ready` function (this means it will load when the document is loaded).

Thirdly I highly recommend to read some about the basics of jQuery - you could start with this:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Edit: Since you really seem to be very confused about everything, here a full example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var defaultMessage = "default message";
                $("#myTextArea").focus(function(){
                    if( $(this).val() == defaultMessage){
                        $(this).val("");
                    }
                }).blur(function(){
                    if( $(this).val() == "" ){
                        $(this).val(defaultMessage);
                    }
                }).val(defaultMessage);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the example above you can also see that I use a newer jQuery-Version - directly from their servers.

Viewing the other answer of Chandrakant:

I don't agree putting the JavaScript part directly into the element. It's not a good practice, since you should always try to split logic & formatting.

Comment: So if the above code works correctly it should display 'default message' in the textbox, correct? Because it is not displaying it for me.

Comment: I can copy & paste the code 1:1 in an empty file and it will work.

Comment: Perhaps it is necessary for me to upgrade to 1.9.1 for it to work then.

Comment: This did not fix the problem. It is still showing up blank on my site.

Comment: Sorry but I can't help. You MUST be using other code than just the above. I mean I only copy & paste it into an empty html site (like test.html), open it and it works...

Answer (score 1):

No need to use jQuery for this , If still you are interested to use jQuery- then use following logic

```
  <input type="text" value="your text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'your text') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'your text';}">
```

Comment: Yeah, inline javascript saves the day !

Comment: Thank you for your response. What do you mean by "no need to use jQuery for this"? You mean using HTML?

Comment: No he means using Javascript. jQuery ist just a framework for Javascript, which makes it a lot easier to code. Just google about both of it, its important to know.

Comment: What method would I use if I did not want to use jQuery?

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I used your method on my website. Thanks again!